# When will Esri re-introduce answered thread, MVP, etc features in its discussion forums?

Tags: esri-company

There are a few simple features that made the "old" Esri forums very useful.

1. Marking a post as answered
2. MVP point structure

Does anyone know when will Esri re-introduce these features in the "new" forums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESRI says it's coming...  http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/14156-When-will-we-be-able-to-mark-posts-as-quot-ANSWERED-quot

Answer (score 2):

Also might be worthwhile to highlight it in the http://ideas.arcgis.com just so that it can be pushed through on both environments.

@KirkKuykendall commented:

> I submitted this as an idea back in June [2010].
>   http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008A3BAAU

Answer (score 0):

It is not a one to one replacement for the old Esri Discussion Forums, but in mid-2014 Esri launched [GeoNet](http://geonet.esri.com):

> GeoNet is the place where you can share, chat, and collaborate on all
>   things geo.  It's your chance to connect with other geospatial
>   enthusiasts around the world.

Its positioning as a replacement for the old Esri Discussion Forums is evident in its [ArcGIS Discussion Forums Migration Strategy](https://geonet.esri.com/docs/DOC-1545) link.